# What does this flask error mean? /usr/local/bin/flask: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: no such file or directory

Tags: python, flask, python-venv

I can tell that Flask is attempting to use python2.7 as an interpreter, but I don't understand why. I created a virtualenv with `python3 -m venv venv`, installed flask, and tried to run an app. I see python3.6 in my venv as expected, so I just don't understand where any attempt to use python2.7 is coming from. I assume this has something to do with my path, but I find that whenever I need to switch between 2 and 3, I need to change my path, inevitably breaking the other version.

Coming from other languages, the promise of "isolated" venvs never seems to work as expected, since I often find python 2 and 3 inextricably mixed up. Is there no way to get an absolute python 2 or 3 environment?

Comment: Yes, it's completely possible and there's no reason to suspect that this issue is inherent in Python and not the result of something you did. That said, the challenge is working out what that thing is.

Comment: It means that the `/usr/loca/bin/flask` script was installed to run with Python 2.7, which is no longer installed.

Comment: If you are using a virtualenv, then use the `flask` script in the `bin` directory of that virtualenv. Or *activate* the venv first with `script bin/activate`.

Comment: I activated the venv before taking any other action on this project. Inside the venv `python --version` is 3.6. I installed flask after activating the venv, so I'm surprised to see it expect python 2.7.

Comment: So is there a `flask` script in the venv `bin/` directory? Because currently, `which flask` seems to point to `/usr/local/bin/flask` and that's clearly not inside your venv.

Comment: there is, and the first line in the file is `#!/Users/{user}/{project}/venv/bin/python3`

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` show? Does it have `/Users/{user}/{project}/venv/bin` in it?

Comment: Also, just because `python --version` shows 3.6 doesn't mean that the virtualenv is active. Does `which python` point to `/Users/{user}/{project}/venv/bin/python` or somewhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have once, in the past, installed Flask with Python 2.7, but that script points to a version of Python that is no longer installed.

Given that the paths involved are `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7`, I'm guessing you are using OS X here and have Homebrew installed. Homebrew  switched out the `python` formula from Python 2 to Python 3 in the recent past and you probably installed Flask for with the Python 2 `pip` command before this change. You should be able to just delete the `/usr/local/bin/flask` script altogether, it is now obsolete and broken.

You also didn't activate your virtualenv. You don't *have* to, but until you do, the `bin/` directory with the correct version of the `flask` script is not going to be available either. When a virtualenv is activated, your `PATH` environment variable is updated to include the `bin/` directory first, by including it at the front of the `PATH` value.

Either qualify the `flask` script to be used by using a path to the virtualenv `bin/` directory, or activate the virtualenv properly.

You can check if your virtualenv is active with

```sh
echo $VIRTUAL_ENV
```

and that should print the path to your virtualenv. You can also verify that `PATH` is set correctly; `echo $PATH` should show the virtualenv `.../bin/` directory as the first entry. If it is not active, activate it by running

```sh
source bin/activate
```

in the virtualenv root directory.

You can run the correct `flask` command by using

```sh
path/to/venv/bin/flask
```

Comment: You are correct about most of these things. I had activated the venv, but I had installed python with Brew in the past, which seems to have left things in a weird state. Removing `/usr/local/bin/flask` then reinstalling caused flask to start with the correct python interpreter.